# Using SCons' VariantDir and Repository to build using custom Generator

Tags: python, scons

I have an almost working SConstruct file. I'm not using any SConscript files currently, and would prefer not to need any in my source repositories (git, not SCons).

Quick summary -- my problem occurs when changing some arguments, then returning to the previous arguments, the same files are rebuilt.

I run `scons -f Builder_repo/SConstruct 'NameOfTargetLibrary.b'` to build a library, `NameOfTargetLibrary.b` from `NameOfTargetLibrary.src`.

`<lib>.b` should be placed in a location that depends on various flags (Debug/Release, 32/64 bit, platform(from list)) like so:

```
topdir
|\-- Builder_repo (containing SConstruct, site_scons\...)
|\-- Lib1 (contains lib1.src, bunch of source files)
|\-- Lib2 (lib2.src, lib2 sources)
\--- BuiltLibs
     |\-- Windows
     |    |\-- Release_32
     |    |    |\-- lib1.b
     |    |    |\-- lib2.b
     |    |    \--- libn.b
     |    |\-- Debug_64
     |    |    |\-- lib1.b
     |    |    |\-- lib2.b
     |    |    \--- libn.b
     |    \--- (Debug_32, Release_64)
     \--- (etc, other targets, currently just one)
```

The command line is something like (split to multiple lines for readability, but only one line in SCons/cmdLine)

```
"abspath to exe" "static path and args" --x64 -- 
    "abspath(lib1.src)" "abspath(BuiltLibs)"
    "abspath(BuiltLibs/Windows/Release_64)" 
    "flags for debug/release, target, bitness"
```

The 'working' SConstruct uses a tool with a `generate(env)` something like:

- construct target directory (e.g. `BuiltLibs\Windows\Release_32`) Store in `env`.
- search for `.src` files
- get containing directory (using `os.path.dirname`)
- add to `env.Repositories(dirname(lib.src))`
- `tgt = env.BLDR(<TARGETDIR>/lib.b, lib.src)`
- `env.Alias(lib.b, tgt)`

The Builder then uses an Emitter to add to the `source` list any `<TARGETDIR>/libx.b` files on which `lib.src` depends (read from a source file). These could instead be added as just `libx.b` if preferable?

The Generator parses the input target and source lists to form the command line, which it returns. With the current configuration, target and source are both relative paths, so probably the `Repository` calls are unnecessary.

When I run

```
scons -f Builder_repo\SConstruct 'lib2.b' DEBUG=0 BITNESS=32 TRGT=Windows
```

(lib2.src depends on lib1.b, due to the emitter), the correct `lib1.b` and `lib2.b` are built and placed in `BuiltLibs\Windows\Release_32\lib{1,2}.b`.

If I repeat the command, then nothing is built and 'lib2.b is up to date'.

Then, I try `scons -f <..> 'lib2.b' DEBUG=1 <other args same>`. Both libraries are built and placed in `BuiltLibs\Windows\Debug_32\lib{1,2}.b` as expected.

When I then try the first command again (`DEBUG=0`) I expect nothing to be built (the lib1.b, lib2.b are still up to date - no sources changed and the previously built files are still in Release_32) but instead they are rebuilt.

I tried to solve this problem by returning a reduced command line when `for_signature` is true, such that the value returned in that case is more like:

```
"abspath to exe" "static path and args" --
     "abspath(lib1.src)" "abspath(BuiltLibs)" "version string"
```

where "version string" is something not affected by the debug/release, 32/64, platform flags (but does change with the source code). This made seemingly no difference.

I tried some variations on this using `env.VariantDir(<TARGETDIR>, '.', duplicate=0)` and then `tgt = env.BLDR(lib.b, Lib1/lib.src)`, `env.Alias(<TARGETDIR>/lib.b, tgt)` or similar, but I haven't managed to improve anything (some configurations just made it always rebuilt, others made it so the dependencies couldn't be found and SCons errored.

How should I be doing this?

---

SConstruct:

```
import os

Decider('make')
Default(None)

# Add command line arguments with default values.
# These can be specified as, for example, LV_TARGET=cRIO
cmdVars = Variables(None, ARGUMENTS)
cmdVars.AddVariables(
    EnumVariable('LV_TARGET', 'Choose the target for LabVIEW packages', 
        'Windows', allowed_values=('Windows', 'cRIO')),
    BoolVariable('DEBUG', 'Set to 1 to build a debug-enabled package', 0),
    EnumVariable('BITNESS', 'Choose the bitness for LabVIEW packages', 
        '32', allowed_values=('32', '64')),
    EnumVariable('LV_VER', 'Choose the version of LabVIEW to use', 
        '2017', allowed_values=('2017',))
)

# Define a list of source extensions
src_exts = ['.vi', '.ctl', '.lvlib', '.vim', '.vit']

env = Environment(variables = cmdVars, ENV = os.environ, tools=['PPL'], PPLDIR='PPLs', SRC_EXTS=' '.join(src_exts))
```

---

**init.py** for the PPL tool:

```
""" SCons.Tool.PPL
Tool-specific initialization for compilation of lvlibp files from lvlib files,
using the Wiresmith 'labview-cli.exe' and the LabVIEW code stored in the 
PPL_Builder GitHub repository.
This module should not usually be imported directly.
It can be imported using a line in SConstruct or SConscript like
env = Environment(tools=['PPL'])
"""

# A reference for this code can be found at
# https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools
# which describes the creation of a Tool for JALv2 compilation.

import SCons.Builder
from SCons.Script import GetOption
import SCons.Node
import SCons.Util
import os.path
import textwrap
import re

import contextlib
import subprocess

# Add warning classes
class ToolPPLWarning(SCons.Warnings.Warning):
    pass

class LabVIEW_CLI_ExeNotFound(ToolPPLWarning):
    pass

SCons.Warnings.enableWarningClass(ToolPPLWarning)

__verbose = False

class LV_BuildPaths:
    """ A simple class to contain the build paths 
        and configuration flags for PPL compilation

        Contains the attributes:
        hwTarget{,Dir}, debug{Opt,Flag,String}, bitness{,Flag}, lv_ver,
        {ppl,storage,copy,topData,data}Dir
    """
    def __init__(self, env):
        # Set the target parameters
        self.hwTarget = env.get('LV_TARGET')
        copyDirExtra = ""
        if self.hwTarget == "cRIO":
            self.hwTargetDir = "cRIO-9045"
            copyDirExtra = os.path.join('home','lvuser','natinst','bin')
        else:
            self.hwTargetDir = self.hwTarget
        # Set the debug parameters
        self.debugOpt = env.get('DEBUG')
        self.debugFlag = int(self.debugOpt)
        self.debugString = "Debug" if self.debugOpt else "Release"
        # Set the bitness parameters
        self.bitness = env.get('BITNESS')
        self.bitnessFlag = ''
        if self.bitness == '64':
            self.bitnessFlag = '--x64'
        # Get the LabVIEW year
        self.lv_ver = env.get('LV_VER')

        # Get important build directory paths.
        # PPL files should be searched for in storageDir
        self.pplDir = os.path.normpath(env.get('PPLDIR', 'PPLs'))
        self.storageDir = os.path.join(self.pplDir, self.hwTargetDir, f'{self.debugString}_{self.bitness}', copyDirExtra)
        self.copyDir = os.path.join(self.pplDir, self.hwTargetDir, copyDirExtra)
        self.topDataDir = os.path.join(self.pplDir, 'Data')
        self.dataDir = os.path.join(self.copyDir, 'Data')

    def __str__(self):
        return (textwrap.dedent(f"""\
        The directories are as follows...
            PPL Dir:      {self.pplDir}
            Storage Dir:  {self.storageDir}
            Copy Dir:     {self.copyDir}""")
        ) 


def _print_info(message):
    """ Disable the output of messages if '--quiet', '-s' or '--silent'
        are passed to the command line """
    if not GetOption('silent'):
        print(message)

def _detectCLI(env):
    """ Search for the labview-cli.exe installed by Wiresmith's VIPackage """
    try:
        # If defined in the environment, use this
        _print_info(f"labview-cli defined in the environment at {env['LV_CLI']}")
        return env['LV_CLI']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    cli = env.WhereIs('labview-cli')
    if cli:
        _print_info(f"Found labview-cli at {cli}")
        return cli

    raise SCons.Errors.StopError(
        LabVIEW_CLI_ExeNotFound,
        "Could not detect the labview-cli executable")
    return None

@contextlib.contextmanager
def pushd(new_dir):
    previous_dir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(new_dir)
    yield
    os.chdir(previous_dir)

def _getHash(env, dir):
    if env['GIT_EXE']:
        with pushd(dir):
            #cmdLine = env['git_showref']
            cmdLine = env['git_describe']
            return subprocess.run(cmdLine, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
    return ''

def _detectGit(env):
    """ Search for a git executable. This is not required for usage """
    git = None
    try:
        # If defined in the environment, use this
        _print_info(f"git executable defined in the environment at {env['GIT_EXE']}")
        git = env['GIT_EXE']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    cli = env.WhereIs('git')
    if cli:
        _print_info(f"Found git at {cli}")
        git = cli

    if git:
        hash_len = 12
        env['GIT_EXE'] = f"'{git}'" # I edited this line compared to the version in the repository, but I don't think it's relevant.
        env['git_describe'] = f'"{git}" describe --dirty="*" --long --tags --always --abbrev={hash_len}'
        env['git_showref'] = f'"{git}" show-ref --hash={hash_len} --head head'
    return None

#
# Builder, Generator and Emitter
#
def _ppl_generator(source, target, env, for_signature):
    """ This function generates the command line to build the PPL.
        It should expect to receive a target as a relative path
        ['<SD>/A.lvlibp'], and source will be either None, or
        ['<src>/A.lvlib'].

        When for_signature == 0, the PPL will actually be built.
    """

    # Get these parameters properly
    run_vi = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.','PPL_Builder','Call_Builder_Wiresmith.vi'))
    cliOpts = ''
    package_ver = "0.0.0.0#sconsTest"

    # These are extracted from the environment
    cli = env['LV_CLI']
    bp = env['LV_Dirs']
    ver = bp.lv_ver
    pplDir = f'{os.path.abspath(bp.pplDir)}'
    storageDir = f'{os.path.abspath(bp.storageDir)}'
    # Dependencies are parsed for the command line. They are already dependencies of the target.
    pplSrcs = source[1:]
    depsString = ""
    if pplSrcs:
        if __verbose:
            _print_info("Adding PPL dependencies: %s" % [ str(ppl) for ppl in pplSrcs ])
        depsString = " ".join([f'"{os.path.basename(ppl.get_string(for_signature))}"' for ppl in pplSrcs])

    cmdLine = f'"{cli}" --lv-ver {ver} {bp.bitnessFlag} {run_vi} {cliOpts} -- '
    lvlib_relpath = str(source[0])
    lvlib_abspath = os.path.abspath(lvlib_relpath)
    git_ver = _getHash(env, os.path.dirname(lvlib_abspath))
    print("git version is " + str(git_ver).strip())

    argsLine = f'"{lvlib_abspath}" "{pplDir}" "{storageDir}" {bp.debugFlag} {bp.hwTarget} "{package_ver}" {depsString}'

    if not for_signature:
        _print_info(f"Making {lvlib_abspath}")

    return cmdLine + argsLine
    #return cmdLine + argsLine

def _ppl_emitter(target, source, env):
    """ Appends any dependencies found in the .mk file to the list of sources.
        The target should be like [<SD>/A.lvlibp], 
        and the source should be like [<src>/A.lvlib]
    """
    if not source:
        return target, source
    exts_tuple = tuple(env['SRC_EXTS'].split(' '))
    src_files = _get_other_deps(source, exts_tuple)
    if __verbose:
        _print_info("Adding " + str(src_files) + " as dependencies")
    env.Depends(target, src_files)
    depsList, nodeDepsList = _get_ppl_deps(str(source[0]), env)
    if nodeDepsList:
        source += [os.path.normpath(os.path.join(env['LV_Dirs'].storageDir, str(pplNode))) for pplNode in nodeDepsList]
    return target, source

_ppl_builder = SCons.Builder.Builder(generator = _ppl_generator, emitter = _ppl_emitter)

def lvlibpCreator(env, target, source=None, *args, **kw):
    """ A pseudo-Builder for the labview-cli executable
        to build .lvlibp files from .lvlib sources, with
        accompanying dependency checks on appropriate source files

        Anticipate this being called via env.PPL('<SD>/A.lvlibp'),
        where target is a string giving a relative path, or
        env.PPL('<SD>/A.lvlibp', '<src>/A.lvlib')
    """
    bPaths = env['LV_Dirs']

    # Ensure that if source exists, it is a list
    if source and not SCons.Util.is_List(source):
        source = [source]

    if __verbose:
        _print_info(f"Target = {target}")
        if source:
            _print_info("Sources = %s" % [ str(s) for s in source])
    if __verbose:
        _print_info("args: %s" % [ str(s) for s in args ])
        _print_info("kw: %s" % str(kw.items()))

    tgt = _ppl_builder.__call__(env, target, source, **kw)
    return tgt

def _scanForLvlibs(env, topdir=None):
    # Maybe check this...
    if not topdir:
        topdir = '.'

    bPaths = env['LV_Dirs']
    lvlibList = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        # if any of files ends with .lvlib, add to the list
        lvlibList += map(lambda selected: os.path.join(root, selected), filter(lambda x: x[-6:] == '.lvlib', files))
    for lib in lvlibList:
        # Set up the possibility of building the lvlib
        (srcDir, libnameWithExt) = os.path.split(lib)
        # Add the source repository
        if __verbose:
            _print_info("Adding repository at: " + srcDir)
        env.Repository(srcDir)
        # Add the build instruction
        lvlibpName = libnameWithExt + 'p'
        tgt = env.PPL(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(bPaths.storageDir, lvlibpName)),lib)
        if __verbose:
            _print_info(f"Adding alias from {libnameWithExt+'p'} to {str(tgt)}")
        env.Alias(lvlibpName, tgt)

def _get_ppl_deps(lvlib, env):
    lvlib_s = str(lvlib)
    lvlib_name = os.path.basename(lvlib_s)
    mkFile = lvlib_s.replace('.lvlib','.mk')
    if os.path.isfile(mkFile):
        # load dependencies from file
        depVarName = lvlib_name.replace(' ',r'\+').replace('.lvlib','_Deps')
        f = open(mkFile, "r")
        content = f.readlines() # Read all lines (not just first)
        depsList = []
        for line in content:
            matchedDeps = re.match(depVarName+r'[ ]?:=[ ]?(.*)$', line)
            if matchedDeps:
                listDeps = matchedDeps.group(1).replace(r'\ ','+').split(' ')
                depsList = ['"' + elem.replace('+', ' ') + '"' for elem in listDeps]
                nodeList = [ env.File(elem.replace('+', ' ')) for elem in listDeps]
                return (depsList, nodeList)
        raise RuntimeError("Found a .mk file ({mkFile}) but could not parse it to get dependencies.")
    #print(f"No .mk file for {lvlib_name}")
    return ('', None)

def _get_other_deps(source, exts):
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(str(source[0]))
    if __verbose:
        _print_info(f"Searching {parent_dir} for source files...")
        _print_info(f"Acceptable extensions are {exts}")
    src_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_dir):
        src_files += [os.path.join(root, file) for file in files if file.endswith(exts)]
    return src_files

def generate(env):
    '''Add builders and construction variables to the Environment.'''
    env['LV_CLI'] = _detectCLI(env)
    env.AddMethod(lvlibpCreator, "PPL")
    _detectGit(env)

    bp = LV_BuildPaths(env)
    _print_info(bp)
    env['LV_Dirs'] = bp

    # Search for all lvlib files
    _scanForLvlibs(env)

def exists(env):
    return _detectCLI(env)
```

Comment: Please post the source to the tool in question. Without it we'll be grasping at straws.

Comment: @bdbaddog Added all of the source code. It's a little verbose in places and some parts could almost certainly have been cut before pasting, but obviously given I'm asking for help I probably shouldn't decide exactly what is or isn't relevant after you asked for the source.

Comment: Too much logic there. Why do you need to have git in this bit of logic? If you want a git tool separate that out.   Also run scons --debug=explain and post. Also run --taskmastertrace=trace.log and pastebin that somewhere.

Comment: As is often unsurprising, problem exists between chair and keyboard... The dependencies included by the Emitter included a file which is generated by the build. This causes the rebuild. Testing with that file removed from the list produces the expected results (i.e. no rebuild when returning to the same command line options). Probably using the default rather than `Decider('make')` might have helped here. I'll take a look at the wiki again because I'm pretty sure I've read an example that discusses version-generated file tagging somewhere there. I'll post back once I find it and implement.

Comment: Yes. I think there's a couple implementations of version file.  AddPreAction is one way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As briefly described in the comments, the reason for the rebuilds was the use of `Decider('make')` (i.e. checking by timestamp) with the effective globbing of source files catching an autogenerated file.

This was easily seen when running `scons --debug=explain` as suggested by bdbaddog in the comments to the question.

Although slightly brittle, the simplest solution is to modify the emitter, leaving the following (see the `--->` mark) :

```
def _ppl_emitter(target, source, env):
    """ Appends any dependencies found in the .mk file to the list of sources.
        The target should be like [<SD>/A.lvlibp], 
        and the source should be like [<src>/A.lvlib]
    """
    if not source:
        return target, source
    exts_tuple = tuple(env['SRC_EXTS'].split(' '))
    src_files = _get_other_deps(source, exts_tuple)
--->filtered_files = list(filter(lambda x: "Get PPL Version.vi" not in x, src_files))
    if __verbose:
        _print_info("Adding " + str(filtered_files) + " as dependencies")
    env.Depends(target, filtered_files)
    depsList, nodeDepsList = _get_ppl_deps(str(source[0]), env)
    if nodeDepsList:
        source += [os.path.normpath(os.path.join(env['LV_Dirs'].storageDir, str(pplNode))) for pplNode in nodeDepsList]
    return target, source
```

By removing this file, the target no longer has an explicit dependency on the generated file (this is independent of the Decider call).

Additionally removing the `Decider('make')` line from the SConstruct file allows the entire source repository to be deleted and redownloaded without triggering rebuilds.

As a side note, the Git-specific code was also removed and placed inside the code called by the Builder - in this way, it is additionally (to the reduction of code benefits) only called if required for a rebuild (rather than every time SCons runs).